# Picking the right sensor for a military style alarm

Tags: arduino, proximity-sensor, motion

as a "squad engineer" of our airsoft team, I have been asked to create a device that will help us with our "capture the hill" tournaments.

As I mostly work with software, I have an hard time picking the right sensor to use. My first idea would be to build something similar to a *trail camera*, used by hunters to study the preys trails. In order to do so, I thought about getting a PIR sensor and link it to an Arduino Micro I have in my drawer from another project. Then, I could use a spare team radio to transmit alarm codes (morse tones).

My sensor specifications are the following:

- outdoor operation capable
- ~10m range
- ~60° angle
- at least 24h operation on battery (sharing the Arduino power supply)
- false positives resistant

Is PIR the right technology to pick in this case ? If so, I really need to know if there are some sensors with the aforementioned specifications; all the Arduino DIY projects I have seen so far employ short range sensors. I would prefer something already packaged (fresnel + diode) from an european dealer.

In the following picture, you can see what I thought.

[image: airsoft crew detector]

I have evaluated those other solutions also:

- steel/nylon tripwire: I would prefer the device to stay undetected as long as possible (it is not a claymore mine, but a silent alarm)
- hacking an airsoft claymore mine (small PIR range, remote unit useless)
- laser tripwire: the reflector (or external laser) unit adds usage complexity, detection is only linear
- doppler radar: my understanding is that this kind of device is only good for linear detection of movement to/from the unit. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: Unless you play at night, PIR is likely not the system you want.

Comment: @Passerby, I understand you are talking about direct sun exposition. What about if I install the sensor away from direct sun ? Does it change anything ? FYI, we play both at night and daytime.

Comment: Indirect sunlight reflecting into the pir sensor's view will also trigger it. The wind blows and leaves or grass shaking will trigger it.

Comment: @Passerby, what you say is reasonable. Do you think I have other options than putting a tripwire ?

Comment: IMHO, A set of laser trip wires would be your best bet. You could even plant battery lasers around a tree x distance away, and string some sensors around said tree for a wide area. If battery life is a problem, pulsing the laser in a constant pattern (think pwm) would decrease the current use, while still being fast enough to detect breaks.

Comment: PIR sensors aren't that bad, they have some compensation for ambient sunlight and small signals. The main limitation is only picking up movement at right angles, not people coming towards the sensor.

Comment: Has anybody prior experience or knowledge about the X-band/radar detectors ? [link1](http://www.conrad-electronic.co.uk/ce/en/product/502667/Hygrosens-RAD-MOD-Radar-Motion-Detector-Module-Operating-voltage-8-15-Vdc) [link2](http://www.parallax.com/product/32213).

They seem to be better than they used to.

Comment: @pjc50 Do you know any PIR sensor model that could fulfill the specification list ?

Comment: Just one comment on the laser system. You could go even more stealth by choosing a wavelength not seen by humans. There are plenty of near UV/IR lasers and sensors.

Answer (score 1):

What about ultrasonic sensors? SparkFun carries a variety of sensors, ranging from ~$30-$100, and it looks like some of them have ranges that get close to your 10m requirement. The one issue is angle; you may have to use more than one to cover a 60° swath.

Your concern with radar would apply here too: it will only measure distance (or Δdistance) from the sensor. But to me this is almost a good thing; it detects "presense" instead of motion, so it could not be foiled by moving really slowly like a motion sensor is. You could program your Arduino to do collect say a hundred readings when powered on, and calculate thresholds to trip the alarm based on, say, the difference between the max and min reading (eg. `int high_threshold=max+(max-min);` `int low_threshold=min-(max-min);`)

The benefit I see of ultrasonic over PIR is that the readings should be fairly stable through a variety of conditions (lighting, temperature, etc), whereas a PIR will need to compensate for the variation and/or suffer false alarms. And of course the benefit over laser/actual tripwire is ease of setup.

This will probably consume more power than a PIR, but it shouldn't be too much. [This sensor](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11724) claims to draw 3.1mA when powered at 5V, meaning it should last ~160h on a 500mAh 9V battery (regulated to 5v; this doesn't take into account losses from the regulator), but of course the Arduino and radio will cut that a lot shorter.